# How to filter out nodes with the same parent as the current node in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Trying to filter out nodes with the same parent as the current one on a tree using the filter function. So far when using some value e.g.

```
tree.nodes(root).filter(function(d) { return d.size <= 20000; })
```

Gives me those nodes with size less than or equal to 20000, tried to extend this to get nodes with the same parent like this

```
tree.nodes(root).filter(function(a, d) { return a.parent ==  d.parent; })
```

This returns a null result, how am I supposed to write it so I get the correct result

Have managed to do this with the global maximum like this

```
node.append("circle")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return root.children ? d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(nodes, function(d) { return d.size;})]).range([0, 100])(d.size)  : 100;});
```

But would like to filter the nodes array in d3 max to apply it to only those nodes with the same parent as the current

Comment: what is the _a.parent_ here...nodes with same parent is within a.children array..can you put up a fiddle

Comment: Trying out the radial tree example here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550 trying to size the circles on the nodes  by a value, this was straight forward but then I realize its better to have different scales for different groups depending on the maximum and minimum of the group, where group means nodes with the same parent and that is where I am stuck

Comment: so you are saying that children having same parent are in same group and they should be in same color..is that the requirement..

Comment: I adopted the a.parent from the separation function, figured the same logic should work here as well. I should add I am learning D3 by fiddling through examples since the tutorials so far seem too basic compared to the examples

Comment: Yes that is the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the same example referred by you  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

You can color child nodes having same parent using this:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5).style("fill", function (d) {
    if (d.parent){
        return colors(d.parent.name);
    } else {
        return "steelblue";
    }
}).style("stroke", function (d) {
    if (d.parent){
        return colors(d.parent.name);//this will return same color for same parent name
    } else {
        return "steelblue";
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

For variable radius based on size, make scale as you are doing in the question:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(nodes, function (d) {
    return d.size;
})]).range([0, 100]);
```

Here i am doing this once and not making the scale function every time as you are doing in the function which calculates the radius.

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) {
    return (d.size ? scale(d.size) : 4);
})
```

Check the size presence b'coz in some cases its not present so radius comes as NaN(not a number) that may be the reason why its not working for you.
I have updated the fiddle with the above changes

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/mLm34pc4/4/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Had already figured out the coloring but cant seem to do the same for scales, want to use a linear scale to size the circles but want each group to have a different scale since some groups have much larger values. Have managed to do this for the global maximum like this

Comment: Thanks but had already figured out the colors but struggling to figure out the sizes, have edited the question to provide some more info. Have also tried writing a stand alone function to separately compute the nodes and calling it in the linear scale definition but it didn't work.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve with this _ return root.children ? d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(nodes, function(d) { return d.size;})]).range([0, 100])(d.size)  : 100;}_
do you want radius to be governed by a parents children count?

Comment: Nope, would like it to be governed by the size attribute in the data  but the ranges vary widely so I am trying to dynamically set the maximum domain value for each group to the maximum size in the group

Comment: Updated my answer and teh fiddle.

Comment: Thanks this helps, had not realized some of the entries were missing the size values but the domain is still using the global maximum as in the maximum for all nodes so some circles are much bigger than others and occlude them and others are so small u have to work hard to see them

Comment: I am not sure if this can be achieved ...however on hover may be we can show the radius to increase. This is one example http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8324872 but they have kept the node radius such that it does not overlap...